# In how many ways can I rearrange teams such that no one repeats teammates?

Tags: combinatorics

I have rewritten this problem into simpler problems but I cannot figure out any answer yet. All of them have people in a starting arrangement. The solution to all is counting the number of rearrangements such that **no one meets a teammate from the original arrangement**.

In order from hardest to easiest, the questions are:

1. I have $n$ people arranged into teams. Team $i$ has $n_i$ people. How many ways can I rearrange the people into "uniform" $m$-sized teams? For my specific case, $n=48$, $m=12$ and $1\leq n_i\leq5$.
2. I have $n=t\times s$ people arranged into $t$ teams of $s$ people each. How many ways can I rearrange the people into $t$ teams of $s$ people again?
3. Question 2 with $n=48, t=12, s=4$.

All my atttempts at a solution eventually run into brute force, to keep track of how many people each team has already given. And I feel like it is impossible to brute force combinations of $48$ people.

Comment: Why can no one meet a teammate from their original arrangement? For example, for question 1, if you have an arrangement from $n=6$ people and $m=3$, and then swap one person from each team, then you still have people who meet teammates from the original arrangement, but they are different team arrangements.

Comment: @Bergson Because I don't want them to. My goal is to count the number of rearrangements such that no one meets a teammate from the original teams.